# Enabling TDE on Azure SQL Using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, tde

I am new to Python and I am trying to write some small scripts top remediate my Azure environment. I am trying to test enabling TDE on Azure SQL databases, but I can't see any sample code to help me out.

Am I going  on the right way using the `TransparentDataEncryptionStatus` command? I am not really sure where to go from here.

This is for an Azure Function

```
mssql_client = SqlManagementClient(credentials, sql_subscription)
database_settings = mssql_client.databases.create_or_update(sql_resource_group, sql_server, sql_db, TransparentDataEncryptionStatus
```

What goes next?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Transact-SQLto Manage transparent data encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-azure-sql#manage-transparent-data-encryption-by-using-transact-sql) in Python:

```
 ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET ENCRYPTION ON
```

Here's the example code:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET ENCRYPTION ON')
cnxn .commit()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I going on the right way using the TransparentDataEncryptionStatus
>   command?

Yes! You are on the right track.

**create_or_update** method creates or updates a database's transparent data encryption configuration.

The only change i see in your code is properly passing the TDE, which should be as below:

```
database_settings = mssql_client.transparent_data_encryptions.create_or_update(sql_resource_group, sql_server, sql_db, status=TransparentDataEncryptionStatus.Enabled)
```

or

```
 database_settings = mssql_client.transparent_data_encryptions.create_or_update(sql_resource_group, sql_server, sql_db, status='Enabled')
```

Please find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-sql/azure.mgmt.sql.operations.transparentdataencryptionsoperations?view=azure-python)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I'm now getting the error "TypeError: create_or_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'parameters'", this is my code
mssql_client = SqlManagementClient(credentials, sql_subscription)
db_id = mssql_client.databases.get
database_settings = mssql_client.databases.create_or_update(
    sql_resource_group, 
    sql_server, 
    sql_db, 
    status='Enabled'
)

Comment: I have updated the answer. The problem here was that in order to enable TDE, we need to use **transparent_data_encryptions** and not **databases** property of SqlManagementClient class. Would you please validate it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay Anish! I only just got back to working on this. The answer is **database_settings = mssql_client.transparent_data_encryptions.create_or_update(group_name, server_name, database_name, status=TransparentDataEncryptionStatus.enabled)**

Answer (score 0):

I've created a blog post that shows the steps needed to setup BYOK TDE on Azure SQL DB which basically made of two steps.
a. set up the server key
b. set the key as the encryption protector

more about it in my post here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/enabling-tde-on-azure-sql-db-server-using-python/ba-p/3840472

the core if it is here (partial code):

```
 tde = ServerKey(
    server_key_type=KeyType,
    uri=KeyURI
    )

server_key = sql_client.server_keys.begin_create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    SERVER,
    SERVER_KEY,
   tde
 ).result()

print("Attempt to apply the server key as encryption protector... ")
sql_client.encryption_protectors.begin_create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME,
    SERVER,
    "current",
    {
        "server_key_name":SERVER_KEY,
        "server_key_type":KeyType
    }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
database_settings = mssql_client.transparent_data_encryptions.create_or_update(
    group_name, server_name, database_name,
    status=TransparentDataEncryptionStatus.enabled)
```